# update StatefulBuilder from outside

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to update a StatefulBuilder state form a showDialog, but I only can call the _setstate1 inside the StatefulBuilder. Is there a way to call _setstate1 from outside

this widget should be updated:

```
String image= "assets/images/1.png";

      Widget updateMe(){
        return StatefulBuilder(builder: (_context, _setState1) {
          return Image.asset(image);
        });
      }
```

this showDialog widget should execute the update:

```
  updateTheImage() {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
          content: Container(child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              _setState1(() {
                String image= "assets/images/2.png";
              });
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.check),
          ),)
          );}
        );
}
```

thanks

Comment: *"but I only can call the _setstate1 inside the StatefulBuilder"* - you can use `ValueListenableBuilder` in such case

Comment: Seems like you're initializing a new local variable "image"

String image= "assets/images/2.png";

remove "String" from the above line.

See if this works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by using ValueListenableBuilder

Answer (score 0):

can you explain more what are you trying to achieve? and in what way the dialog is connected to the `updateMe()` function? it's a bit vague to be honest.